# adding Identity Framework on existing asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-identity

I want to add identity frame work in my existing asp.net web api project, which already uses Database first  approach for Entity framework( I have a single employee table for CRUD operation) and I have a autogenerated connection string in web.config because it is database first approach,

here is the connection string (
<addname="atishEntities"connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=atish;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
)

So I did the following things:

```
1.First inherits my context class with Identity context of type IdentityUser:

namespace EmployeeService
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class atishEntities : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public atishEntities()
            : base("name=atishEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            
            
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}

2.Then I use UserManager class like below:

public class AppUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AppUserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser> store)
       : base(store)
        {
        }

        // this method is called by Owin therefore this is the best place to configure your User Manager
        public static AppUserManager Create(
            IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new AppUserManager(
                new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context.Get<atishEntities>()));

            // optionally configure your manager
            // ...

            return manager;
        }

    }

3.Then Since Identity is based on OWIN I configure OWIN too:

 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new atishEntities());
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<Authenticate_data.AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);

            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<AppRole>>((options, context) =>
            //    new RoleManager<AppRole>(
            //        new RoleStore<AppRole>(context.Get<MyDbContext>())));

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
            });
        }
    }

4. Then added this in web.config file

<appSettings>
    
    <add key="owin.AppStartup" value="EmployeeService.Startup.Configuration" />
</appSettings>`enter code here`

5. Then I added a webform having three text boxes and one button(Register) (i.e username, password, confirm password and Register) and then in Register button click event I added following code and I got exception here in this line below "**IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text)**", I also try to add migration after doing all this things but I got this error "**Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.**"

protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

            var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                StatusMessage.Text = string.Format("User {0} was created successfully!", user.UserName);
            }
            else
            {
                StatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Connection String?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="atishEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=atish;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Normally you can [scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). Have you tried that already?

Comment: No, but my project is not core and it will not support core library